# Return a resource group object and List<string> with Azure function C#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-sdk-.net

I am creating an API where I can retrieve the list of resource groups in a given subscription or retrieve a resource group ID, but I am unable to return both

```
[Function("getRg")]
public async Task<HttpResponseData> GetRgs([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = "rg")] HttpRequestData req,
        string? rg, string sub,
        FunctionContext functionContext)
{
    ArmClient client = new ArmClient(new DefaultAzureCredential());

    SubscriptionCollection subscriptions = client.GetSubscriptions();
    SubscriptionResource subscription = await subscriptions.GetAsync(sub);

    ResourceGroupCollection resourceGroups = subscription.GetResourceGroups();

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(rg))
    {
        string resJson = "";
        ResourceGroupResource resourceGroup = await resourceGroups.GetAsync(rg);
        resourceGroup = await resourceGroup.GetAsync();
        resJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(resourceGroup.Data.Id);

        _logger.LogInformation($"requested RG: ${resJson}");

        var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");
        response.WriteString(resJson);

        return response;
    }
    else 
    {
        var rgList = new List<string>();

        foreach (var rgItem in resourceGroups)
        {
            rgList.Add(rgItem.Data.Name);
        }

        _logger.LogInformation($"rg list: {rgList}");

        var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/html, charset=utf-8");
        await response.WriteAsJsonAsync(rgList);

        return response;
    }
}
```

When I try to get the list by not providing an rg name parameter, I get the following error:

> System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.getRg. System.Private.CoreLib: Result: Failure
>
> Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (The format of value 'text/plain, charset=utf-8' is invalid.)

What should the format be in the response header in this case? And am I doing it right?

The second behavior I am not understanding is also, when I try to get the id of one rg by using this line:

```
resJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(resourceGroup.Data.Id);
```

I expect to get the id only, however I get a different large object.

Appreciate your help!

Comment: `resourceGroup.Data.Id` is of type [ResourceIdentifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.core.resourceidentifier?view=azure-dotnet) which is a class. That's why you are getting large object serialized.

Comment: Why are you not setting Content-Type as application/json ?

Comment: Also, when you use `WriteAsJsonAsync` that sets the HEADER (so you don't need to set any headers) and also the status code to 200. -or- you can pass in your OWN status code, instead.